# Importing a namespace from Unity Packages c# - The type or namespace name 'Steamworks' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, using

I am trying to import Steamworks from the Steamworks.NET package that I imported through the unity package manager.

I can clearly see that the Steamworks.NET package was installed and that it contains the namespace Steamworks.
[image]

However, when I actually try to use this namespace, like this:

```
using Steamworks;
```

I get the error:

```
Assets\Scripts\SteamIntegration\SteamManager.cs(15,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Steamworks' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This makes no sense to me - The namespace clearly exists in the project.  Why can I not use it / How can I use it?

Comment: You have to add as a Reference from menu Project : Add Reference then browse for the dll.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an [Assembly definition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) for your scripts.

In that case you additionally will need to [reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#reference-and-assemblies) the assembly definition of according package(s).

In your case the file starting with `com.rlabrecque....`

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be that you are not working with the correct Platform,
make sure that on your build settings you are working with "Windows, Mac, Linux" platform.

[image]

There could be other reasons but first check that.